# How can I split csv file read in langchain

Tags: python, csv, langchain, large-language-model

this is set up for `langchain`

```
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

text_splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=100, 
                                             chunk_overlap=20, 
                                             length_function=len)
```

now I need to read a csv file

```
import csv
with open("test.csv") as f:
    # test is an iterator
    test=csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
```

this does not work because `test` is an iterator

```
# object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()
chunks=text_splitter.create_documents(test)
```

`text_splitter.create_documents` accepts `str`. If I read a `.txt` file and pass it, it works. so I need to convert `_csv.reader` type to `str`. I tried

```
     chunks=text_splitter.create_documents("".join(test)
```

I get

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: it happen because you are trying to use a _csv.reader (your test variable) as a list object.

Comment: What about reading the whole file, f.read(), to get one big string?